# Divide a number n into x random parts such that sum of x parts is equal to number n

Tags: javascript, random

Here n is the number, p is number of parts:

```
let n = 100;
let p = 11;
let obj = [];
console.log(Math.round(n/p))
while (p != 0){

  let value = Math.round(Math.random() * n);
  obj.push(value);
  n -= value;
  p--;
}

console.log(obj);
```

This is the output :
`[ 68, 18, 1, 5, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]`

Comment: what is the problem with it?

Comment: I don't want zeros in my final array plus the main constraint is its sum must be equal to number n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subtract the wanted minimum value from the sum for distributing and take the rest for the last element.

```js
let n = 100;
    p = 11;
    result = [];

while (--p) {
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - p - 1)) + 1;
    result.push(value);
    n -= value;
} 
result.push(n);

console.log(...result);
console.log(result.length, result.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```